# Помогите, как импортировать в проект модуль java.desktop?

Tags: java, android, модули

Только сейчас решил уйти в 8-й Java на новые версии. Появилась необходимость импорта вышеназванного модуля. На SO уже были подобные вопросы, но мне всё равно не совсем понятно, как это работает. Там везде что-то в духе "Клонируйте реопзиторий, и дальше что-то там...". И нигде не показано, как по-другому импортировать сторонние модули и модули стандартной бибилиотеки Java.

Подскажите, как импортнуть `java.desktop`? Я даже не нашёл нигде ссылку на его скачивание.

Сейчас у меня есть только `module-info.java`:

```
module TestProj.app.main {
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

Я пишу приложение для Андроид, и мне нужен класс `java.awt.Color` для конвертации цвета HSV<->RGB.

Comment: Может быть вы хотите импортировать java.awt.desktop? java.desktop виже впервые
Или если вы хотите сделать декстопное приложение, то думаю легче будет использовать javaFX?

Comment: Java на Андроид урезанная, в ней нет большинства классов из пакета `java.awt.*`. Если какие-то библиотеки или модули зависят от `java.awt.*`, то они должны быть адаптированы для работы под Андроид.

Comment: А нельзя ли где-то скачать отдельно этот пакет или вытащить его из JDK?

Comment: Скорее всего, запустить десктопное AWT-приложение на Андроиде не так-то просто. Например, если погуглить, то [тут была попытка](https://code.google.com/archive/p/awt-android-compat/) завести AWT на Андроиде. Но судя по описанию проекта, это сделать не удалось.

Comment: Хорошо, может кто-нибудь знает библиотеку для конвератции цветов на Java? Я не нашёл ни одной